# Average IQ of Mensa

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I was wondering, what the average IQ at Mensa is. Mensa is a group of people with an IQ of at least 130. And the IQ is normally distribed with $\mu = 100$ and $\sigma = 15$.

My idea was this:

To get the mean of a function in interval $[a,b]$ I have to calculate

$$\bar{f}(x) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)\; dx$$

So the mean $p$ is

$$p = \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{b-130} \int_{130}^{b} \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x-100}{15}\right)^2}dx$$

And then I just have to calculate, which IQ corresponds to this $p$.

Is my idea correct? How do I solve this integral and calculate the limit?

Comment: There is a cutoff on the right too! Perhaps at $b = 150$. Not everybody is attracted by the idea of spending time with people who are proud of their IQ of 130. But this will not affect the average much.

Comment: Calculation methods aside, what we are missing here is that not everybody who has an $IQ \ge 132$ will want to join Mensa. Since the IQ distribution is for the general population. So it is not be correct to use this distribution to estimate Mensa's average IQ. I would also assume that Mensa's IQ distribution should be proportionally a lot denser close to the limit 132, and drops down more quickly than the distribution for the general population as we move higher in the range.

Comment: Technically, the average IQ of a population is, by definition, 100.

Comment: Many people who could qualify for MENSA membership are either not snobby enough, or too snobby, to join. (I'm being a bit hard on them. Out in Middle Nowheresville, MENSA can be a valid way to find others who share your interests. Closer to a population center, there are better ways to do so and MENSA does degenerate to puffery.)

Comment: There is an interesting math problem here independent of one's opinion of MENSA.

Comment: @OrangeDog Isn't that the definition of IQ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The $x$ corresponding to the mean value of a density $f$ is not (in general) equal to the mean $x$.

Instead, you want to compute the mean of $x$, weighted by $f$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int_{130}^\infty xf(x)dx}{\int_{130}^\infty f(x)dx}.
\end{equation}

This can also be interpreted probabilistically: we are looking for the expectation $E[X \mid X\geq 130]$, which is obtained by the integral
\begin{equation}
E[X \mid X\geq 130] = \int_{130}^{\infty} x p(x) dx,
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the conditional density of the probability distribution, obtained by
\begin{equation}
p(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\int_{130}^\infty f(t) dt},~x\geq 130
\end{equation}

Note that this answer is focused on the mathematical content, i.e., not questioning the assumptions. For various reasons I suspect this method does not capture the average IQ of Mensa (e.g., probability of joining Mensa might vary as a function of IQ even above the threshold).

Answer (score 8):

If the distribution is continuous uniform, then your idea is correct. But since IQ test scores typically follow what is known as a normal (or Gaussian) distribution, then you should use the **left censored and shifted variable** method. The expected value using this method can be obtained by
$$
\text{E}[(X-d)_+]=\int_d^\infty (x-d)f(x)\ dx.
$$
In your case $d=130$ and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(100,15)$. Actually, the minimum accepted IQ score to be a Mensan on [the Stanford-Binet Intelligence Scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford-Binet_Intelligence_Scales) is $132$.

**ADDENDUM :**

If you consider this case using the conditional distribution, then for a given value of $d$ with $\Pr[X>d]>0$, in your case $\Pr[X>d]=0.02$ because a Mensa member is a person who scores at or above the 98th percentile on certain standardized IQ or other approved intelligence tests, then for $Y=X-d$ given that $X>d$, its expected value is
$$
\text{E}[Y|X>d]=\frac{\int_d^\infty (x-d)f(x)\ dx}{1-\Pr[X\le d]}.
$$

Your problem is similar to the problem: [Mensa (The High IQ Society)](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/mensa-the-high-iq-society/?group=Is2kBeo81mRO) that I posted on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/).

Comment: Um, I think the question is about $E(X \mid X \geq d)$ (see my answer). Your integral counts all subjects below 130 as zeros, while actually they should be ignored when we are computing the average of those exceeding the threshold. Is there some connection of the left-censored shifted mean and the conditional mean that I'm not aware of (perhaps specific to Gaussians?)?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I've added the extra information before you commented. Thanks anyway... **:)**

Comment: Hi, Tunk-Fey, and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I've edited your answer, in accordance with the guidelines given in our [help/behavior], to remove the extra "signature" you appended to it. Your posts here are already automatically signed with your username, avatar and a link to your user page, which is where you may include any extra information about yourself if you want.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen OK, if that is the rules what could I do but obey it. Thank you for the information. I really appreciate it. **:)**

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Nope - this is not a left censored random variable:  it is a left truncated distribution.

Comment: @wolfies I've checked my statistics text book and it's said that it's a left censored and shifted variable. According to my text book, it is said left censored because the value less than $d=0$ and left truncated if the value less than $d$ is unknown. In this case, I use term the value less than $d=0$ but it's unreasonable that's why I use Bayesian inference.

Comment: There is no observed data nor unknown parameters in this question, and thus this is not an 'inference' problem at all. Using conditional distributions is not limited to Bayesians if the random variables involved are well defined.

Comment: @Tunk-fey You should find yourself another stats textbook ... For the correct answer, see Juho Kokkala's answer.

Comment: @wolfies My text book is published by John Wiley and Sons, Inc.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey So nu?  .............

Comment: @wolfies The answer above is correct.   Please do not downgrade other textbooks because not everybody is using the one you wrote.  The solution above is in agreement with how the bbook defines left censored random variables.

Comment: @Integrals Whether the 'solution' above is in agreement with how some book defines left censored random variables is entirely irrelevant as to whether the above (and/or said book) is correct or not.

Comment: @Integrals Consider a simpler population with only 4 people, IQs $(115, 125, 135, 145)$ (keep the Mensa limit at 130 and assume everyone eligible joins). Is the average IQ of Mensa members in this population $E[(X-d)_+]=(0+0+5+15)/4 = 5$ or $E[X\mid X\geq d] = (135 + 145)/2 = 140$?

Comment: @wolfies You implied my answer was incorrect and told me to refer Juho Kokkala. If so, why [my calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=132%2B%28integrate+%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*%28x-132%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29%5E2%29%2Cx%3D132..infinity%29%2F%28integrate+%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29%5E2%29%2Cx%3D132..infinity%29) and ...

Comment: @wolfies (cont.) [Juho Kokkala's calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integrate+%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*%28x%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29%5E2%29%2Cx%3D132..infinity%29%2F%28integrate+%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29%5E2%29%2Cx%3D132..infinity%29) yield the same answer? W|A confirms both our calculation yield the same answer. In this case, I'm not trying to say that our answers are correct.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey your link to "your calculation" contains adding $d$, which isn't explained in your answer. Furthermore, the conditional part is only an "addendum" in your question. Using 130 as the limit (as specified in the question), [your first approach](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integrate+%28x-130%29*%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29^2%29%2Cx%3D130..infinity%29) equals $E((X-d)_+) \approx 0.127$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey (cont.) While [your addendum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integrate+%28x-130%29*%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29^2%29%2Cx%3D130..infinity%29+%2F+%28integrate+%281%2F%2815*sqrt%282*pi%29%29%29*exp%28-0.5*%28%28x-100%29%2F15%29^2%29%2Cx%3D130..infinity%29) equals $E(X-d \mid X\geq 130) \approx 5.60$, while my answer is 130 + your second answer = 135.60. Your answer currently consists of 1. incorrect approach 2. addendum: almost correct approach, and thus is neither correct nor produces the same result as mine.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala $$\text{E}[X-d|X>d]=\Delta\text{IQ}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{E}[X|X>d]=d+\Delta\text{IQ}.$$

Comment: That is correct, but an explanation of that is missing from your answer. Anyway, my biggest beef with your answer is that it sounds like using the conditional expectation was somehow optional.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I really don't wanna continue any argument with you. You can say your answer is correct and mine is incorrect or completely false. It's OK for me. I'll just be fine. **:)**

Comment: @Integrals Thank you for being in my side and defending me. I really appreciate it. You're Jeff, right? Once again, thanks... **:)**

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Indeed, Integrals=Jeff :)

Comment: I was not aware we were supposed to be "on somebody's side" or "defending users", naively I figured we were here to ask and to answer (if possible, accurately) mathematical questions. Users pointing mistakes in one's answers are actually rendering a service to the OP, not "attacking" them...